Permission to send critical sound on alerts
I am creating an application in flutter environment and I want to add a functionality where my device would emit a sound even if it is silent or in 'Do Not Disturb' mode. In this case, I would need any suggestions on how to do this or any implementation in specifically in flutter.
I am already having alerts as well as sound but when the device is on silent or DND, I am not getting any sound that I need.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
